# What's the correct conversion from JSON to map?

Tags: json, grails

I am creating REST request to an API, using the httpbuilder.

The only accepted JSON format is

```
{
"attributes" : [
  {
     "name" : "attr-name",
     "values" : [
        "attr-value"
     ]
  }
 ]
}
```

This is accepted and succeeded in Postman-ReSTClient

tTo convert it to map is something like this

```
 [attributes:[name:attName,values:[value:value1]]]
```

or

```
 [attributes:[[name:attName,values:[value:value1]]]]
```

I'm receiving an error which says the request body is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about the Postman API, I can't help you. If you are asking if the JSON code matches your Ruby code, then no, they don't match.

The curly braces {} mark hashes (key:value pairs), and the braces [] mark arrays (a list of values with no keys).

You have this:

```
require 'json'
m = [attributes:[name:"attName",values:[value:"value1"]]]
print m.to_json()

> [{"attributes":[{"name":"attName","values":[{"value":"value1"}]}]}]
```

But, you want this:

```
require 'json'
m = {attributes:[{name:"attName",values:["1"]}]}
print m.to_json()

> {"attributes":[{"name":"attName","values":["1"]}]}
```

Rule of thumb, does it have a key? use {}. Is it a list of values? use []

Comment: using your answer i try something like this HashMap m = [attributes:[[name:"attName",values:["1"]]]]
  println new JsonBuilder( m ).toPrettyString() ang got what i need. Thanks man. cheers

Comment: What does this question have in common with ruby?

Comment: It has to do with me misreading grails as rails. Other than that, the answer has to do with general JSON formatting. I can edit my response if it bothers you that much.